# Flat vertex painting, or face painting?

Tags: faces, texture-painting, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

Vertex painting is far too *soft* for me:
[image]

I'm looking to paint something more like this (not exact, but close enough):

[image]

Instead of smooth interpolation, color interpolation should be done on a *per-face* basis and not smoothed between faces. And if possible I would like to paint faces, not vertexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select faces in *Edit* mode
2. Switch to *Vertex Paint* mode and press *Face selection masking for painting* button (3D view -> bottom panel -> button with cube icon (next to layers selection)
   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to fill selected face with the selected color.

[image]

This way, you can also normally vertex paint your model but painting will be limited to selected faces only.

Comment: I found your answer really helpful! As a test, I assigned pure red/green/blue to different faces of a mesh, and set each of those RGB channels to mask in a different procedural texture for bump/displacement. This technique will be useful for projects where just a few properties of a material need to be different for certain mesh faces. Of course UV mapping works too, but then we get concerned with what the unwrap looks like, and it's dependent on a texture... this just feels simpler and cleaner for certain use cases. [Example blend.](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/oPYnb9ag/)